# Radios and Channels

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a question related to radios (interfaces) and channels.

Based on the materials available I have understood the radio is a frequency and channels are logical frequency spectra of radio. Is it correct?

If a wireless router has a single radio and 3 orthogonal channels can it send the same information to three different devices on three different channels? Or will it use only one channel at a time for communication to all three devices?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the router in question, as I'm sure someone has developped a router that can utilize multiple channels at the same time much like you can use both high and low band frequencies (2.4 GHz & 5.0 GHz) at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the router you specify is the dual band router.For example a router with 2.4GHz is used (single radio). As per the standard it has 14 channels in which 3 are orthogonal(1,6,11) and others are overlapping channels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The router you have specified is a dual band router. Assume a network consisting of 3 nodes(routers) with 2.4 GHz radio with 14 channels in which 3 are orthogonal and remaining are overlapping channels. For simplicity assume only orthogonal channels are used. Can node 1 send signal to node 2 on channel 1 and to node 3 on channel 2 simultaneously.

Comment: So I googled it (and I use the lmgtfy link because its shorter) http://lmgtfy.com/?q=multi%20channel+router and they do exist. When I mentioned the dual band router I was not stating they were using multiple channels on the same frequency.